# Cannot Access HttpContext.Current when using Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

```
Thread sendEmails = new Thread(() => AnnounceAllEmployee(Requisition_num));
sendEmails.Start();
```

When i access a method that use : `var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;` in my code , i got error
**HttpContext.Current is null** i tried to access it inside thread ,but still got error that it's null.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current is only available for the main thread, a new thread that is spawned from the controller will have a different context.

What you could do is pass it as a parameter.

You will need to modify AnnounceAllEmployee to handle the new HttpContext parameter; `AnnounceAllEmployee(... , HttpContext hc)`

```
   HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
   Thread sendEmails = new Thread(() => AnnounceAllEmployee(Requisition_num, httpContext));
```

This will not clone the http context but pass it by reference only hence it will not consume more memory.

EDIT: It seems that once the request is done, since it is passed by reference, the httpcontext of the main thread that we are trying to access will return null on some properties.

Comment: Dear , once it's access the AnnounceAllEmployee Method it become NULL even though i pass it with parameter .

Comment: @QaisAlmomany i updated the answer, it seems that we need to do copying. What specific properties of HttpContext do you need?

Comment: The Current  property.

Comment: The current property is of type HttpContext. So what do you need inside that Current?

Comment: i need the HTTP context to render the partial view to a string.

Comment: ` var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, partialView.ViewName).View;

            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
            {
                using (var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    view.Render(new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, view, partialView.ViewData, partialView.TempData, tw), tw);
                }
            }`

Answer (score -2):

**Need to Keep it in Mind**

If you try to get the `HttpContext.Current` from another Thread it will not be accessible and `HttpContext.Current` will always be `null` when passing from one thread to another thread

So in place of `Thread` you need to use `Task` to get the `HttpContext.Current`

As Follows:

```
public async Task GetCurrentContextAsync()
{
  //Current Context will be available in Task
  var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
}
```